# Java not returning correct result for tree search when incrimenting versus adding one

Tags: java, binary-tree

Hopefully this will be an easy question. I am trying to find the level of a given unique number on a binary tree. My binary tree is such that

```
[1,2,3,null,4,null,5]
```

I am trying to check if the heights of two nodes are the same, in this case, 4 and 5. I implemented a solution as follows.

```
public int findNodeHeight(TreeNode root, int nodeValue, int height){
    //if end of tree, exit loop
    if(root == null){
        return -1;
    }
    //if we found the value, return height
    if(root.val == nodeValue){
        return height;
    }

    //check the left
    int left = findNodeHeight(root.left,nodeValue,height++);
    if(left!=-1){
        return left;
    }
    //check the right
    int right = findNodeHeight(root.right,nodeValue,height++);
    if(right!=-1){
        return right;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

However this doesn't work, and it returns a height of 2 for 5 (which is correct) and a height of 1 for 4 (which is incorrect). However if I change the ++ operator to

```
height+1
```

as follows:

```
public int findNodeHeight(TreeNode root, int nodeValue, int height){

    if(root == null){
        return -1;
    }

    if(root.val == nodeValue){
        return height;
    }

    //check the left
    int left = findNodeHeight(root.left,nodeValue,height+1);
    if(left!=-1){
        return left;
    }
    //check the right
    int right = findNodeHeight(root.right,nodeValue,height+1);
    if(right!=-1){
        return right;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The solution now works. Why is it wrong to use the ++ operator in the method call?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `height` when it is initially 2 and you call `height++` two times? And what is this value when you call `height+1` two times? I guess then you'll understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the method is executed with `height` value when you pass `height++` and then the value of `height` is incremented by 1.

`height++` is a post-increment operator, which would increment the value of `height` by 1 only **after** the execution of the statement. `++height` is a pre-increment operator, which would increment the value of `height` by 1 **before** the execution of the statement.

If you use the pre-increment operator on `height`, it might work fine in cases where the second `findNodeHeight` call is not made at all, but might result in anomalies when the second `findNodeHeight` call is made since it would have updated the value of `height` on the second call. Hence it would be advisable to use `height+1` in case it provides the right result, since the increment operators might not provide the right result always.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use ++ in the method call ***in this situation*** because, `var++` increments `var`, but it returns the **original** `var`, which means you are simply passing `var`. Instead if you used `++var`, it would both increment `var`, and pass the newly incremented value.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because

```
height++
```

returns height and height and increments height by one and

```
height+1
```

just returns height+1 and it doesn't increments the height which would also be a problem.

Comment: Why do you think `++height` would work better? Why do you think it is correct pass different `height` values to the two recursive `findNodeHeight` calls?

Comment: i don't think it would work better it's just an alternative that works, actually height + 1 is better for this since it's useless to store the height increment .

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I don't think it would work. Using `++height` two times is something different than using `height+1` two times. Thus OP would pass a different `height` value on the second `findNodeHeight` call

Comment: thanks! you are right, i edited the  answer so it's no longer wrong.